# How to restrict the execution of other container until all the scripts are executed on DB container in docker in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

I want to wait till the complete execution of the scripts in mysql container or oracle container then the next execution should happen in docker-compose. I have tried depends_on, wait-for-it.sh but I am not able full fill my requirement. All the containers starts simultaneously.

Comment: You need to write logic in dependent container, so that process in that will start only after execution of script in DB container completes

Answer (score 0):

docker only registers when the container is up and running. It doesn't register if the processes inside the container are ready.

You can check if the other service is ready to accept connection with:

```
 bash -c "while ! nc -w 1 -z other_service 5432; do sleep 0.2; echo 'waiting for other_service...'; done;"
```

This is an infinite loop, that stops as soon as the other service starts to accept connections.

So you just need to add this line at the beginning of your startup-command. (also you need to have nc and bash installed inside your container)

Answer (score 0):

I have added sleep with timeout of 300 second in the Entrypoint in dockerfile of the other application so that it will sleep for some time till the time DB scripts executed successfully. I estimated the timeout roughly by checking the total time taken by scripts to execute.

Added below in dockerfile

Entrypoint sleep 300 && other command